# A question on the set of fixed point subgroups of group automorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. For every $f\in Aut(G)$ we denote by $Fix(f)$ the subgroup of fixed points of $f$. Which are the finite groups $G$ such that the set $\{Fix(f) \mid f\in Aut(G)$} forms a sublattice of the subgroup lattice of $G$?

Comment: Would it be more natural to consider $\{ Fix(H): H \leq Aut(G) \}?$ ( That is, the fixed subgroups of all subgroups of ${\rm Aut}(G) ).$